# My G hotkey doesn't work, how to rework it?

Tags: edit-mode, particle-edit-mode

When I wanted to edit my donut, I suddenly found that it has no reaction when I hit <kbd>G</kbd>, is there something I can do to fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: Try turning off Proportional Editing (letter O).

Comment: You can switch to the Move gizmo (on the left “toolbar”) and use that instead.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett@TheLabCat Hi, thanks for your help. I reopened blender and it just work again. Still thanks! BTW, I have another problem about shadows , do you know how to fix it? below is the link to my question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255690/how-can-i-make-my-donut-has-shadows-just-like-another-picture

Answer (score 1):

You might have accidentally turned on snapping (magnet icon by proportional editing). I figured this out myself when I had the same issue. But if you meant to use snapping, then I'm not sure.