# how can I make my donut has shadows just like another picture?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, units

[image]

[image]

how can I make my donut  has shadows just like another picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're currently in *Solid* mode, while BGuru is in *Rendered* mode, switch to *Rendered* mode (the fourth button on the top right of your 3D view). Also make sure that you've enabled the *Shadow* option of your light.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, make sure you have enabled the *Scene Lights* option (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oizDu.png) to see the lights in *Rendered* and *Material Preview* mode